# How to use 'text-align:centre' to horizontally centralise items on a page?

Tags: html, css

I have recently started to learn HTML and CSS, and have just started to create a simple website, just to experiment with the language. On my homepage, I have a div, which will contain the navigation bar, and my title. The navigation bar should be at the top right hand corner of the div, and then the title, should be directly in the centre of the div.

But whenever I try to use `text-align:centre`, it will never put it in the centre. This is what I have so far, https://jsfiddle.net/3qqjfy24/1/. Please can somebody tell me how I can get the 'Harry Brown' header to sit directly in the centre of the div (horizontally and vertically).

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul id="bar">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Projects</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
    <h1>Harry Brown</h1>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#nav {
background-color: orange;
width: 100%;
height: 250px;
}
#bar {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#bar li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Tahoma, 'Geneva', sans-serif;
}

#nav h1 {
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Tahoma, 'Geneva', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you sure to Create a Design on your own? There are thousands of free Designs out there which will help save you time and problems. Check oswd.org

Comment: Why don't you use Margin like this https://jsfiddle.net/sank8893/3qqjfy24/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
#nav h1 {
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Tahoma, 'Geneva', sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/feyvor8m/

```
#nav {
 background-color: orange;
 width: 100%;
 height: 250px;
}
#bar {
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
#bar li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
 border-color: white;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 2px;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: Tahoma, 'Geneva', sans-serif;
}

#nav h1 {
 color: black;  
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: Tahoma, 'Geneva', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
}
```

I hope I understood your question well. No need to float the menu and no need for absolute position of h1.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about what questions to aks or not to ask and how to ask good question.
you have to read through the css tutorials, There are lots of tutorial in the web.

And for your question's answer

you should use text-align. It aligns text and other inline content. It doesn't align block element children.

```
#nav h1 {
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align:center 
    font-family: Tahoma, 'Geneva', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this, hope this is what you want.

**The header is EXACTLY at the center of the div and the bar is at the right hand side of the screen.**

**css**

```
#nav {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;

}
#bar {
  float: right;
  postition: absolute;
  display: inline;
}

#bar li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Tahoma, 'Geneva', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Tahoma, 'Geneva', sans-serif;
  postition: absolute;
  margin-left: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Here is the working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/3qqjfy24/16/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any of the answers or comments address this explicitly, so I'll just spell this out for you:

`text-align: centre;` is an invalid property value. It will never work. The CSS spec demands the American English spelling, "center."

So `text-align: center;` is what you're looking for.